# In Azure AD B2C, How long is the verification code from a txt message valid?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When using [MFA in B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-mfa), I assume the text message expires after some time, is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**At this time, [Azure AD B2C MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-mfa)'s verification code has an expiration around 3 to 5 minutes and cannot be configured.**

It's worth noting that B2C's MFA leverages [Azure AD's MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication). While not currently documented, make sure to monitor that documentation for an eventual more official answer on how the verification code works and its expiration logic/duration.